# How load a model saved using `saver.save` in Tensorflow's Java API

Tags: java, tensorflow

I am trying to read a model from disk using the new Java API.

[The one example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/examples/LabelImage.java) to use Tensorflow's Java API shows how to read a `.pb` model file that has both graph definition and the parameter weights.

On the Python side, Tensorflow suggests to use a `Saver` object to save a model to disk. It creates a `.meta` file that has the definition and has `.data` files for the weights. In Python, I use `new_saver=tf.train.import_meta_graph(var_filename)
new_saver.restore(sess, model_filename)` to read the model from the disk.

How do I do it in the Java API?

Answer (score 0):

The [`SavedModelBundle`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/63467d9/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle.java#L27) class is probably what you're looking for. In particular, `SavedModelBundle.load()` will return a `Session` which you can use to execute the saved model.

Note that this feature was added relatively recently to the Java API so it doesn't exist in the binary release yet, so you'll have to [build the Java API from source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/63467d9/tensorflow/java/README.md#building-from-source) till TensorFlow 1.1 is released.

Comment: Great, thanks. My current solution is to save both the graph def and the weights using `freeze_graph` and then read in Java. This class looks promising. I'll wait until the official release to try it in my code,

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, train the model on a hadoop cluster using the python interface and use the model and the learned parameters to predict in java.

- To save the model

  you have to use SavedModelBuilder. Here you find guidance:
  https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic.html
  and you can use their mnist example con construct the function signatures
  https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py

Usage is very simple on the java side:

```
SavedModelBundle load = SavedModelBundle.load(modelDir, "serve");
        float[][] resultArray;
        try (Graph g = load.graph()) {
            try (Session s = load.session();
                 Tensor result = s.runner().feed("data", data).fetch("prediction").run().get(0)) {
                resultArray = result.copyTo(new float[10][1]);
            }
        }
        load.close();
        return resultArray;
```

To get the names of the feed and the fetched operations you can print your signatures, and use the input and output value names.

```
print(prediction_signature)
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py#L119

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Java library that has the functionality that you described in your problem. You can input a saved_graph (freezed model) and then run inference on it. Check it out if you want: [JavaTF](https://github.com/preafixed/Java-TF)

If you want you can just follow the instructions I provided on the Readme file, and test the functionality.